# Routing to a different application on button click

Tags: java, nginx

I have created 2 java web application in order to learn nginx. 
Currently I am able to route to one of my web app on hitting of `localhost` by modifying the `nginx.conf` file.

In my app , there is a `click here` link. I am trying to route to my second web app on click of that. How can I achieve this?

My `nginx.conf` server directive snippet-:

```
 server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/Hello_World/;
        }
    location /saytime {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/FirstServletProject/FirstServlet/;
        }
```

First server in running on `http://127.0.0.1:8081/Hello_World/`

Second server is running on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/FirstServletProject/FirstServlet/`

My Hello_World `index.html` file-:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="saytime">Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My Hello_World servlet-:

```
package com.example.helloworld;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloWorldServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/saytime")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloWorldServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<html><body><h1 align='center'>" +
        new Date().toString() + "</h1></body></html>");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Even hitting link `http://localhost/saytime` , it is not forwarding to that app.

Updates after changes as per Victor's answer-

Getting `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`

```
Type Status Report

Message /FirstServletProject/FirstServlet/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your **HelloWorld** Server has to redirect to the **FirstServletProject** Server when the user clicks on the HTML `<a>` link.

There is some problems in here:

1. Your `/saytime` controller is in the same server than the index. So it will never be able to process the request in another app.
2. If you move the controller to the **FirstServletProject** the redirection will be possible, but you will still have to change the URL specified `<a>` link from the relative path to the index's Server `<a href="saytime">` to an absolute path `<a href="http://localhost:80/saytime"`
3. If you are redirecting with Nginx service you won't need the `@WebServlet("/saytime")` annotation. You are already telling Nginx than when he receives a request on */saytime* it should redirect it to http://127.0.0.1:8080/FirstServletProject/FirstServlet/
4. Also have a look to Nginx service. Some times an error in the configuration doesn't allow the service to start. Use `systemctl status nginx` for seeing if it's running. If it's not use `journalctl -e` for debugging the error.

#### EDIT

After discussion with OP none of the provided solutions worked.

Try to create another server block in Nginx conf (different from the default one) and upstream blocks for each server:

```
server {
      listen 8082;
      location / {
         proxy_pass http://helloworld;
      }
      location /saytime/ {
         proxy_pass http://firstservlet;
      }
   }

   upstream helloworld {
      server http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
   }

   upstream firstserver {
      server http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
   }
```

I think you should **un**comment the `@WebServlet("/saytime")` annotation.

Comment: I tried as per your comments - 1. Moved my controller to `FirstServletProject`. 2. Commented the `@WebServlet("/saytime")` .3. Changed the href to absolute path. Still I am not getting the response. Could you please help with an example.

Comment: Are you sure that Nginx is running correctly? Are you using Linux or Windows?

Comment: I am using a Mac system . Yes it is running. The first routing `/` is happening properly. when I hit `localhost`

Comment: What is happening if you try to make the request from the web browser? Install Postman, perform the request and paste or explain the response you got.

Comment: Updated the question with the response I am getting. URL is getting changed to `http://localhost/saytime` . In the message `Message /FirstServletProject/FirstServlet/` looks like it is trying to route

Comment: Thanks Victor . I could solve it using your pointers in the answer.